# Use Kubernetes to deploy a single app to multiple servers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, k3s, k3sup

I'd like to deploy a single app to multiple servers in one time.

I'm using `Kubernetes` and `K3S` to easily deploy containers.
Basically, I have a master server that I run and multiple servers that are localed in my customers facilities.

Master server was initialized with the following command:

```
k3sup install \
    --ip $MASTER_IP \
    --user ubuntu \
    --cluster --k3s-channel latest \
    --k3s-extra-args "--node-label ols.role=master"
```

Customer's servers were launched with:

```
k3sup join \
    --ip $WORKER01_IP \
    --user ubuntu \
    --server-ip $MASTER_IP \
    --server-user ubuntu \
    --k3s-channel latest \
    --k3s-extra-args "--node-label ols.role=worker"
```

When I want to deploy a new web service on each customer's server, I've tried the following code:

```
helm install node-red k8s-at-home/node-red --set nodeSelector."ols\.role"=worker
```

Problem: Only one single pod is deployed.

What I'd like is to deploy a single pod on each server and make it independent.
Is there a way to do that ?

Comment: If all of the servers are in the same cluster, they should all be able to communicate with each other over the cluster network; you don't usually need a local copy of the application on every server.  If you're trying to have dedicated hardware per user, you might look at general-purpose automation software like Chef, Ansible, or Salt Stack, rather than a cluster system like Kubernetes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here there are two different things that we need to consider.

If the requirement is just to run more number of `replicas` of the `application` a change to the `deployment` template in the `helm` chart or through `values` you can pass number of minimum `replicas` need to be working in the cluster.

Reference [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/) for `deployments`

Coming to next thing, if the requirements is just to run application across all the nodes existing in the cluster, `Daemonsets` is the workload which gives the capability to run across all the existing nodes.

Reference [documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) for `daemonsets`

Again if you are using `helm` to deploy, appropriate templates for either `daemonsets` or `deployments` need to be added or modified based on the existing contents of the `helm` chart.

There are also different [workloads](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/) `k8s` supports so based on requirements they can be picked appropriately.

Comment: `DaemonSet` was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks !